# Настройка DNS записей на хостинге доменного провайдера

Tags: dns

Допустим я приобретаю домен у домен провайдера, назовем его `dhost.local`

На хостинге сайта предлагают подключить домен сменив `NS` записи у `dhost.local`.

Могу ли я не изменяя `NS` записи `dhost.local` подключить домен к хостингу. Например просто сменив `A` записи на те что предоставляет хостинг сайта?

Comment: Можете. То, что предлагают, чистый маркетинг.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, а достаточно ли лишь изменения A записей, для того что бы сайт открывался?

Comment: С чего бы он не открывался.

Comment: Когда у меня были сайты на всяких хостингах, я только так и делал - NS у провайдера доменов, A-записи указывают на хостинг.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, спасибо за разъяснения. Оформите пожалуйста как ответ, я приму. Возможно кому то пригодиться в будущем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что предлагает хостинг, это маркетинг. Для функционирования сайта совершенно необязательно, чтобы NS записи были перемещены на хостера. Когда у меня были  сайты на хостингах, я оставлял NS у провайдера домена и указывал в A-записи адрес хостинга.

Более того, в некоторых случаях перемещение NS на хостинг только ухудшает ситуацию. Мне неизвестны российские хостеры и регистраторы доменных имён, которые бы распространяли изменения в записях домена быстрее, чем за несколько часов. Ведущие мировые регистраторы доменных имен распространяют изменения в течение нескольких минут.

Для работы с российскими клиентами, у кого адреса в зоне .ru, я использую следующий подход. Сразу после создания доменного имени перевожу NS на cloudflare. Эта процедура занимает несколько часов. Все дальнейшие изменения в домене (A, CNAME, MX, PTR и проч.) делаю на cloudflare. Эти изменения становятся доступны на локальном компьютере в течение не более, чем 5 минут. Это очень ценно само по себе и, особенно, для оперативного создания поддоменов.